# XGBoost for python is not accepting the shapes of my target

Tags: python, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I have been struggling to get python's xgboost to accept targets due to their shape (I have tried shapes of (-1,1) vs (-1,), format of pandas vs numpy, and LabelBinarizing vs One-hot-encoding the target). Any advice to get this going?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(0, 25, size = (1000, 10))
y = np.random.randint(0, 5, size = (1000, 1))

clf = xgb.XGBClassifier()

x = xgb.DMatrix(x)
y = xgb.DMatrix(y)

clf.fit(x, y)

ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

Answer (score 0):

With XGBoost DMatrix as an input you dont use `clf.fit()`, only `xgb.train()`.  `Clf.fit()` expects array in the input.
References:
[Get started xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html)
[XGBClassifier.fit()](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html?highlight=xgbclassifier#xgboost.XGBClassifier)
[xgboost.train()](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html?highlight=xgb%20train#xgboost.train)

Comment: Uh yes that'll do. Thank you much!